# Результат/состояние выполненного запроса MYSQL записать в файл

Tags: mysql

Таблица БД содержит ~200 млн. строк. Подключаюсь к серверу терминалом по SSH.

Иногда приходится работать с запросами, которые выполняются довольно долго:

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE...
INSERT INTO tbl1 SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE...
OPTIMIZE TABLE tbl1;
```

и т.д.

Во время работы запроса, может оборваться соединение по SSH и сессия подключения к mySQL закроется. При этом СУБД продолжает обрабатывать запрос.

Мне нужно увидеть стандартное сообщение, которое выводит mySQL по окончанию работы над этим запросом (количество затронутых строк, затраченное время, возникшие ошибки и т.д.). Как это сделать? Может быть в файл записать? Подскажите как реализовать.

Comment: А как вы запросы выполняете?

Comment: подключаюсь по SSH. Запускаю mysql в консоли и запускаю запросы. Либо через программу HeidySQL подключаюсь к СУБД на сервере. И тот и другой вариант могут оборваться/зависнуть на длительных запросах

Comment: Можно триггеры написать для запросов ([что-то типа такого](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18765074/12593651)). А, вообще, странно что подобное вручную делаете с таким кол-вом записей

Comment: что-то я не вижу там, чтобы можно было состояние выполненного запроса посмотреть.

Answer (score 0):

Подключаясь по SSH используйте мультиплексоры [tmux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux) или [screen](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen).

Аттач сессий решит вашу проблему. Сессия выполняется независимо от SSH-соединения и  к ней можно подключиться для наблюдения результатов в любой момент.

Если соединение с интернетом неустойчивое (LTE, Wifi) можно использовать совместно с [mosh](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosh_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0)). Эта тулза автоматически переключает соединения когда интернет появляется после оффлайна и делает это не выходя из открытого readline-интерфейса mysql.